# Spivak, Ch. 5, Problem 22: Prove relationship between limits of functions

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification, limits-without-lhopital

> 22. Consider a function $f$ with the following property: if $g$ is any
>     function for which $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} g(x)$ does not exist, then
>     $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} [f(x)+g(x)]$ also does not exist. Prove this
>     happens if and only if $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x)$ does exist.

I will show a solution below. My question is mainly about the underlying logic of the statements in the proof. I believe that my use of certain terms is clumsy, though I think the underlying logic is correct. I would appreciate answers which contribute to polishing the proof, if it is indeed correct.

**First let's consider a result from Problem 8 of Ch. 5, which asked us**

> 8b) If $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)$ exists and $\lim\limits_{x \to a} [f(x)+g(x)]$ exists, must $\lim\limits_{x \to a}g(x)$ exist?

Write $g$ as

$$g = (f+g)-f$$

Then

$$\exists \lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x) \implies \exists \lim\limits_{x \to a} [-f(x)]\tag{1}$$

By assumption

$$\exists \lim\limits_{x \to a} [f(x)+g(x)]\tag{2}$$

$(1)$ and $(2)$ $\implies \exists \lim\limits_{x \to a} (f+g-f)(x) \implies \exists \lim\limits_{x \to a} g(x)$

Therefore, we've shown that

$$\exists \lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x),\exists \lim\limits_{x \to a} [f(x)+g(x)] \implies \exists \lim\limits_{x \to a} g(x)\tag{3}$$

Let's think of this statement as

$$A \land B\implies C\tag{4}$$

What does it mean if $\nexists \lim\limits_{x \to a} g(x)$, ie $\neg C$?

$\neg C \implies \neg(A \land B)\implies (\neg A \land B) \lor (A \land \neg B) \lor (\neg A \land \neg B)$

So for example, if we assume that $\exists \lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)$, ie $A$ is true, then $A \land \neg C \implies A \land \neg B$, ie $\nexists \lim\limits_{x \to a} [f(x)+g(x)]$.

**Back to problem 22 now:**

It asks us to prove that

$$\left[\forall g: \nexists \lim\limits_{x \to a} g(x) \implies \nexists \lim\limits_{x \to a}[f(x)+g(x)] \right] \iff \exists \lim\limits_{x \to a}f(x)$$

Assume $\left[\forall g: \nexists \lim\limits_{x \to a} g(x) \implies \nexists \lim\limits_{x \to a}[f(x)+g(x)] \right]$ is true.

Consider result $(3)$ derived above. Fix the function $f$.

Assume $\nexists \lim\limits_{x \to a}f(x)$.

Now take any function $g$ such that $\nexists \lim\limits_{x \to a} g(x)$.
By assumption (is it right to call this an assumption in this particular part of a proof by contradiction where I assume this relationship is true?) this means that $\nexists \lim\limits_{x \to a} [f(x)+g(x)]$.

However, by $(4)$ we have:

$\neg C \land \neg A \implies (\neg A \land B) \lor (\neg A \land \neg B)$.

That is, $\lim\limits_{x \to a} [f(x)+g(x)]$  may exist or it may not exist. This contradicts what we said was true which is that $\nexists \lim\limits_{x \to a} [f(x)+g(x)]$. Therefore, our assumption that $\nexists \lim\limits_{x \to a}f(x)$ is false.

Therefore $\exists \lim\limits_{x \to a}f(x)$.

To prove the other direction of the $\iff$, assume $\exists \lim\limits_{x \to a}f(x)$ is a true statement.

Now assume that $\nexists \lim\limits_{x \to a}g(x)$.

From $(4)$ we have $A \land \neg C \implies \neg B$.

This means that $\nexists \lim\limits_{x \to a}[f(x)+g(x)]$.

Comment: In the satement of the problem, the limit of $g$ is at $a,$ not $0.$ In that case, what would happen to $f + g$ if $\lim\limits_a f$ did not exist and you considered $g = -f$?

Comment: By the way, your "solution" is wrong. In your notation, you now take $\neg C$ which implies either $\neg A$ or $\neg B$ but $\neg B$ is a hypothesis, so you cannot draw any conclusions of veracity over $A$; by hypothesis $\neg C \implies \neg A \vee \neg B$ is true.

Comment: Typo regarding the $x \to a$ which should be $x \to 0$

Comment: Also, words are superior to symbols when it comes to understanding. Say it in plain English: you want to use the result "if individual limits exist, then the limit of the sum is the sum of the limits", its negation is "if the limit of the sum does not exists, an individual summand has no limit." But since you are given $g$ and $f+g$ without limit, there is not inference over the limit of $f.$

Comment: $\neg C \implies \neg B, \neg C \implies \neg B$ is a hypothesis, $\forall g$. However, we also have the relationship $A \land B \implies C$. If we have $\neg C, \neg B$ and $\neg A$ this relationship is satisfied. However, somehow it isn't true anymore that $B$ has to be false. One can find a counterexample, and I think this is what Spivak does in the solution manual Let me transcribe here the actual solution from Spivak, which is in words:

Comment: if $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x)$ does exist, then it is clear that $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} [f(x)+g(x)]$ does not exist whenever $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} g(x)$ does not exist (this was Problem 8(b) and (c)). On the other hand, if $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x)$ does not exist, choose $g = -f$; then $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} g(x)$ does not exist, but $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} [f(x)+g(x)]$ does exist.

Comment: The last comment you wrote is exactly the solution I proposed you in my very first comment.

Comment: Ok, so this proof basically says: assume $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x)$ exists and this implies the hypothesis is true always. Now assume $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x)$ does not exist, and show a counterexample to the hypothesis. Would my proof be fixed if I said $\neg C \implies \neg A \land \neg B$, and then proceeded to show the counterexample $g = -f \implies \neg C \land \neg A \land B$? Ie we'd have a contradiction, which would mean we'd have shown our assumption of $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x)$ to be false.